# How to populate TABLE OF RECORDS with rows of 2 levels parent-child

Tags: oracle, recursion, plsql, record

I have a table with rows describing a tree, columns are: 
(column `child_num` is unique and used as ***primary key***)

```
TABLE items_tree (
      child_num        number, 
      parent_ref       varchar2(10), 
      child_ref        varchar2(10)
);

TYPE item_rec_type IS RECORD (
      item_id          NUMBER,
      spaces_number    NUMBER,
      parent_ref       VARCHAR2(10),
      child_ref        VARCHAR2(10)
);

TYPE tree_table_type IS TABLE OF item_rec_type%ROWTYPE
    INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

table_tree      tree_table_type;   -- table of all items
```

Example data for table `items_tree` (values of `child_num` are not relevant):

```
parent_ref   child_ref
---------------------------
null         Abraham
Abraham      Isaac
Abraham      Ishmael
Isaac        Jakob
Jakob        Yehuda
Jakob        Josef
Jakob        Benjamin
Yehuda       David
Josef        Efraim
Josef        Menashe
David        Solomon
Solomon      Isaiah
Isaiah       Jeremiah
```

I need to populate `table_tree` records from `items_tree` table. To do so, I am using a package, the `item_rec_type`, `tree_table_type`, `table_tree` are defined in it and two procedures: `print_tree` which retrieves the `ROOT` items of the tree, starts the process and prints the tree from `table_tree`. Second procedure `get_items_by_parent_recursively` is recursive procedure that retrieves all the items or a parent item, e.g. calling `get_items_by_parent_recursively('Abraham')` will add *Isaac* and *Ishmael* to `table_tree`.

The cursor is declared in the package body:

```
CURSOR get_children_cur(c_parent in varchar2(10)) 
IS
  SELECT      parent_ref, child_ref
     FROM     items_tree
     WHERE    parent_ref = c_parent
     ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

The code in `get_items_by_parent_recursively` that retrieves the items for the parent:

```
procedure get_items_by_parent_recursively(p_parent in VARCHAR2(10), p_spaces_number in NUMBER ) 
AS
  l_spaces_number  NUMBER := 0;
  l_child          VHARCHAR2(10);
  l_parent         VHARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  l_spaces_number := p_spaces_number + 3;

  OPEN get_children_cur(p_parent);
  LOOP
     FETCH get_children_cur INTO l_parent, l_child;   
     EXIT WHEN get_children_cur%NOTFOUND;

     IF (l_child is not null) THEN
        v_row_number := v_row_number + 1;
        tree_table(v_row_number).row_num       := v_row_number; 
        tree_table(v_row_number).spaces_number := l_spaces_number; 
        tree_table(v_row_number).parent_ref    := l_parent; 
        tree_table(v_row_number).child_ref     := l_child; 

        -- Calling procedure recursively
        get_items_by_parent_recursively( l_child, l_spaces_number );
     END IF;

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE get_children_cur;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN CURSOR_ALREADY_OPEN THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- CURSOR_ALREADY_OPEN');
  WHEN INVALID_CURSOR THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- INVALID_CURSOR');
  WHEN INVALID_NUMBER THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- INVALID_NUMBER');
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- NO_DATA_FOUND');
  WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- PROGRAM_ERROR');
  WHEN ROWTYPE_MISMATCH THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- ROWTYPE_MISMATCH');
  WHEN STORAGE_ERROR THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- STORAGE_ERROR');
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- TOO_MANY_ROWS');
  WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- VALUE_ERROR');

END get_items_by_parent_recursively;
```

Running this procedure I am getting the exception: `CURSOR_ALREADY_OPEN`.

I have searched for a reply, but none came close to what I need. I will appreciate any ideas.

I will try to make the cursor `get_children_cur` part of the recursive procedure.

Comment: I think the cursor needs to be declared within the procedure body, I do not see the declaration. Have you tried that?

Comment: As well as not showing the cursor, your code is invalid in various other ways (misspelling `vharchar`, including a size in a formal parameter definition, inconsistent names and data type - even the procedure name is too long). [A complete and working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be much more useful, as would expected output. Do you really need PL/SQL for this - seems like something you could do with a hierarchical query or recursive CTE, but depends what output you want...

Comment: The cursor you've shown is also invalid. The column names don't match your table definition, you've constrained the parameter size again, and where is `p_child` coming from? And where is `p_parent` coming from in the open-cursor call in the procedure - is that supposed to be `l;_parent`, or more likely `l_child`? I can guess what you're trying to do and write something for that; but that comes back to why you are using PL/SQL at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @vmachan said, you need to move the cursor definition into the procedure. While you have it in the package specification or body, but outside the procedure, there is one instance of it which is global to the session. Each call to your procedure attempts to open the same cursor; the initial call from `print_tree` succeeds, and your table is populated with 'Abraham'; but then the recursive call tries to re-open it and gets the `CURSOR_ALREADY_OPEN` exception, and stops.

Moving the cursor into the procedure means each call/iteration has its own independent copy. Cleaning up naming and various other issues, this then works:

```
procedure get_items_by_parent(p_parent in VARCHAR2, p_spaces_number in NUMBER) 
AS
  l_spaces_number  NUMBER := 0;
  l_child          VARCHAR2(10);
  l_parent         VARCHAR2(10);

  CURSOR get_children_cur(p_parent in varchar2) IS
  SELECT parent_item, child_item
  from items_tree
  where parent_item = p_parent
  or (p_parent is null and parent_item is null);

BEGIN
  l_spaces_number := p_spaces_number + 3;

  OPEN get_children_cur(p_parent);
  LOOP
     FETCH get_children_cur INTO l_parent, l_child;   
     EXIT WHEN get_children_cur%NOTFOUND;

     IF (l_child is not null) THEN
        v_row_number := v_row_number + 1;
        table_tree(v_row_number).item_id         := v_row_number; 
        table_tree(v_row_number).spaces_number   := l_spaces_number; 
        table_tree(v_row_number).parent_item_ref := l_parent; 
        table_tree(v_row_number).item_ref        := l_child; 

        -- Calling procedure recursively
        get_items_by_parent( l_child, l_spaces_number );
     END IF;

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE get_children_cur;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN CURSOR_ALREADY_OPEN THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- CURSOR_ALREADY_OPEN');
  WHEN INVALID_CURSOR THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- INVALID_CURSOR');
  WHEN INVALID_NUMBER THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- INVALID_NUMBER');
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- NO_DATA_FOUND');
  WHEN PROGRAM_ERROR THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- PROGRAM_ERROR');
  WHEN ROWTYPE_MISMATCH THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- ROWTYPE_MISMATCH');
  WHEN STORAGE_ERROR THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- STORAGE_ERROR');
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- TOO_MANY_ROWS');
  WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('   Exception -- VALUE_ERROR');

END get_items_by_parent;
```

Inventing a `print_tree` based on what you describe:

```
procedure print_tree is
begin
  get_items_by_parent(null, 0);

  for i in 1..table_tree.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(to_char(table_tree(i).item_id, '99999') || ' '
      || lpad(' ', table_tree(i).spaces_number, ' ')
      || table_tree(i).item_ref);
  end loop;
end print_tree;
```

... calling that now works, and produces 13 indented records:

```
 1    Abraham
 2       Isaac
 3          Jakob
 4             Yehuda
 5                David
 6                   Solomon
 7                      Isaiah
 8                         Jeremiah
 9             Josef
10                Efraim
11                Menashe
12             Benjamin
13       Ishmael
```

As @XING said, you can get the same result more simply with a different for of cursor loop:

```
procedure get_items_by_parent(p_parent in VARCHAR2, p_spaces_number in NUMBER) 
AS
  l_spaces_number  NUMBER := 0;

  CURSOR get_children_cur(p_parent in varchar2) IS
  SELECT parent_item, child_item
  from items_tree
  where child_item is not null
  and (parent_item = p_parent
    or (p_parent is null and parent_item is null));

BEGIN
  l_spaces_number := p_spaces_number + 3;

  FOR r IN get_children_cur(p_parent)
  LOOP
    v_row_number := v_row_number + 1;
    table_tree(v_row_number).item_id         := v_row_number; 
    table_tree(v_row_number).spaces_number   := l_spaces_number; 
    table_tree(v_row_number).parent_item_ref := r.parent_item; 
    table_tree(v_row_number).item_ref        := r.child_item; 

    -- Calling procedure recursively
    get_items_by_parent( r.child_item, l_spaces_number );
  END LOOP;
END get_items_by_parent;
```

or even:

```
procedure get_items_by_parent(p_parent in VARCHAR2, p_spaces_number in NUMBER) 
AS
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT parent_item, child_item
    from items_tree
    where child_item is not null
    and (parent_item = p_parent
      or (p_parent is null and parent_item is null)))
  LOOP
    v_row_number := v_row_number + 1;
    table_tree(v_row_number).item_id         := v_row_number; 
    table_tree(v_row_number).spaces_number   := p_spaces_number + 3; 
    table_tree(v_row_number).parent_item_ref := r.parent_item; 
    table_tree(v_row_number).item_ref        := r.child_item; 

    -- Calling procedure recursively
    get_items_by_parent( r.child_item, p_spaces_number + 3 );
  END LOOP;
END get_items_by_parent;
```

Of course, you don't need to use PL/SQL or a table at all, you can use a hierarchical query:

```
select rownum, lpad(' ', level * 3, ' ') || child_item as item
from items_tree
start with parent_item is null
connect by parent_item = prior child_item
order siblings by child_num;

    ROWNUM ITEM                                              
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1    Abraham                                        
         2       Isaac                                       
         3          Jakob                                    
         4             Yehuda                                
         5                David                              
         6                   Solomon                         
         7                      Isaiah                       
         8                         Jeremiah                  
         9             Josef                                 
        10                Efraim                             
        11                Menashe                            
        12             Benjamin                              
        13       Ishmael
```

but presumably this is a PL/SQL exercise. If you aren't required to use a recursive procedure you could still populate your table from a similar query, using `bulk collect`.